# filtering large data table by two variables in R

Tags: r

With the RWE below, I am one step short of achieving my desired result. I can identify the unique combinations, but I want to obtain a data.table of all three columns (`A`,`B` and `C`)

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10)
b <- c(1,2,1,1,5,5,6,1,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,2)
c <- c(1,1,3,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,20)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b, c)
head(df1)
#
library(dplyr) # example using dplyr package
df1 %>%
  distinct(a,b)
#
unique( df1[ , 1:2 ] ) # using base R
```

These commands return the unique combinations of `a` AND `b` from `df1`, but I want the output to include the `c` values in the data.frame also.

Comment: `df1[!duplicated(df1[, 1:2]), ]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `.keep_all` as TRUE.  In the default, it is `FALSE`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   distinct(a, b, .keep_all = TRUE)
```